# Angular 5 Render content of template without parent template in table

Tags: html, angular

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I have bit tricky situation here.

I have a table like so:

```
<table>
 <th>...</th>
 <app-custom-rows *ngFor="let t..." [customAttribute]="somevalue"></app-custom-rows>
</table>
```

My app-custom-row component has a bunch of rows as such:

```
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
<tr>...</tr>
```

So final output is coming to be like this:

```
<table>
 <th>...</th>
 <app-custom-rows>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
 </app-custom-rows>
 <app-custom-rows>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
 </app-custom-rows>
 <app-custom-rows>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
 </app-custom-rows>
</table>
```

I tried with selector also but have no element to render it with which will not be there. And ng-container doesn't render anything at all. So is there any other stuff which will just disappear and let its content be there.

Comment: Pass the all the rows to the component and iterate it inside the component

Comment: I wish I could but the app-custom-row is kind of recursive call. It has to render itself within itself for multiple levels. so it won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have found a workaround, albeit accidentally, and it works in chrome. So all I needed to do is to set the display property to contents on `<app-custom-rows>` and it passed its content to its parent directly. like this:

```
app-custom-row{
 display:contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several solutions for this common problem, I propose two:

### Use <ng-container>

You say that `ng-container` doesn't render anything, but this is not how it works (well, except if you're confusing it with `ng-template`), since `ng-container` has been designed to group elements and don't interfer with style and template. You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue).

### Style your component as table row

The other solution is not using any `<tr>` at all, and just let your `<app-custom-rows>` to behave as a table row (your browser won't notice the difference!).

To achieve this, add the following style to your `app-custom-row` custom css:

```
:host {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had researched quite a lot of solutions and couldn't find any which solves the issue.
1) when I use the app-custom-row as directive instead of selector, I need to put it on some element. I tried with ng-container but I also need to bind some value and hence it throws 'el.setAttribute is not a function'
2) I had tried to set the display:table-row but again I have table rows inside of app-custom-rows so ultimately it's throwing it out of table structure

Comment: You should change also the way you use your app-custom-rows. You should rename it as a singular name and use it as it was your usual table row, and customize it with @Input. If it doesn't solve your problem, then I think to have misunderstood the point :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear. The custom component is itself having 6 tr elements in it. I am passing half a dozen of values using @Input. Everything else is working fine. Just the data which needs to be displayed in entire table is displayed in the very first column.